# Authentication error using new Pulumi azuread module

Tags: azure, pulumi

I've installed the latest Pulumi azuread module and I have this error when I try a pulumi preview:

```
Previewing update (int):

     Type                          Name                Plan     Info
     pulumi:pulumi:Stack           test-int
     └─ azuread:index:Application  test                         1 error

Diagnostics:
  azuread:index:Application (test):
    error: Error obtaining Authorization Token from the Azure CLI: Error waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1
```

my index.ts is very basic:

```
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import * as azure from "@pulumi/azure";
import * as azuread from "@pulumi/azuread";

const projectName = pulumi.getProject();
const stack = pulumi.getStack();
const config = new pulumi.Config(projectName);

const baseName = `${projectName}-${stack}`;

const testRg = new azure.core.ResourceGroup(baseName, {
    name: baseName
});


const test = new azuread.Application("test", {
    availableToOtherTenants: false,
    homepage: "https://homepage",
    identifierUris: ["https://uri"],
    oauth2AllowImplicitFlow: true,
    replyUrls: ["https://replyurl"],
    type: "webapp/api",
});
```

Creating resources and AD application with the old module azure.ad works fine.

I have no clue what I am missing now....

**EDIT:**

index.ts the old way

```
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import * as azure from "@pulumi/azure";

const projectName = pulumi.getProject();
const stack = pulumi.getStack();
const config = new pulumi.Config(projectName);

const baseName = `${projectName}-${stack}`;

const testRg = new azure.core.ResourceGroup(baseName, {
    name: baseName
});

const test = new azure.ad.Application("test", {
    homepage: "https://homepage",
    availableToOtherTenants: false,
    identifierUris: ["https://uri"],
    oauth2AllowImplicitFlow: true,
    replyUrls: ["https://replyurl"]
});
```

Result of pulumi preview:

```
Previewing update (int):                                                                                                                                                                   

     Type                     Name                Plan       Info                                                                                                                          
     pulumi:pulumi:Stack      test-int                                                                                                                                           
 +   └─ azure:ad:Application  test                create     1 warning                                                                                                                     

Diagnostics:                                                                                                                                                                               
  azure:ad:Application (test):                                                                                                                                                             
    warning: urn:pulumi:int::test::azure:ad/application:Application::test verification warning: The Azure Active Directory resources have been split out into their own Provider.

    Information on migrating to the new AzureAD Provider can be found here: https://terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/guides/migrating-to-azuread.html                                   

    As such the Azure Active Directory resources within the AzureRM Provider are now deprecated and will be removed in v2.0 of the AzureRM Provider.                                       

Resources:                                                                                                                                                                                 
    + 1 to create                                                                                                                                                                          
    2 unchanged
```

EDIT 2:

I'm running this on Windows 10:

- az cli = 2.0.68
- pulumi cli = 0.17.22
- @pulumi/azure = 0.19.2
- @pulumi/azuread = 0.18.2
- @pulumi/pulumi = 0.17.21

Here are my principal permissions for Azure Active Directory Graph:
[image]

And the permissions for Microsoft Graph:
[image]

Comment: Could you share the old and the new versions?

Comment: @Swell did you do a `az login` or set the ARM env vars so that the `azuread` provider can connect to your subscription? See https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/clouds/azure/setup/

Comment: Yes, I've created a service principal and I can use Pulumi without a problem up to this issue.

Comment: @Swell I ran your program above verbatim and couldn't reproduce your issue. Can you please check installing the latest packages for `pulumi/pulumi`, `pulumi/azure` and `pulumi/azuread` fixes it for you? For reference, my versions were 0.17.21, 0.19.2 and 0.18.2 respectively. My Pulumi CLI version is 0.17.21 and Az CLI version is 2.0.50. I am on a Mac. To be sure that my Az CLI creds were working, I logged out (`az logout`) and then logged back in again (`az login`) and checked that default subscription using `az account show`.

Comment: @praneetloke the post is updated with versions and permissions

Comment: Thanks @praneetloke, logging out and back in solved the issue for me. Previously was getting `Error obtaining Authorization Token from the Azure CLI: Error parsing json result from the Azure CLI: Error waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1`, while `az` and `npm` packages were at their most recent version and `az account show` were working

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue and after hours I realized Fiddler was somehow interfering with the Az CLI running